# How can I add a new CSS class to <ul> tag?

Tags: css, wordpress, class, html-lists

I want to assign a new CSS class to default `<ul>` widget in Page/Post creating page in wordpress. How can I do this?

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Depending on your theme, I would have a look in `sidebar.php` or `functions.php` if your theme registers the sidebars in `functions.php` that is..

Comment: Just apply the css rules to your `themeroot/style.css` file. Whats the problem?

Comment: The thing is previous developer has set the <ul> style to 'none'. If I remove it, perhaps some of the styling issues may occur. I don't want to do that. Instead I want to add a CSS class in admin panel add new page/post page's <ul> widget.

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to stylize a button within the visual editor of the WordPress admin area? Or are you trying to stylize ul's in a sidebar widget? It seems to me that some of the terminology here is mixed/unclear, but maybe I'm missing something. BTW, have you tried jus creating a descendant selector style in CSS (eg http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector)

Comment: @evanv:I've uploaded an image. Your first suggestion is right. I'm trying to stylize a button within the visual editor of the WordPress admin area

Comment: Unless you're pretty darn familiar with WordPress, template hierarchies, and adding admin themes (eg http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes), I'd recommend just using http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-admin-css/

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is create and upload a new style rule for the `<ul>` with the class name you want to assign to it in your `themes/themename/style.css`.

**Example**

```
ul.new-style {
    /* styles */
}
```

Then add in a HTML list using the "Text" view on the editor.

[image]

**Example**

```
<ul class="new-style">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

You can also hard code styles if you want a quick fix: `<ul style="list-style-type: disc;">`

Comment: The thing is client doesn't familier with html and he only uses Visual tab to create posts/pages. I want to set that CSS class via programmetically. Whenever the user click on that icon, the new CSS class should be assigned to that list autometically.

Comment: I don't think this can be done but you could create a wrapper for the content so that all `<ul>` elements within the wrapper will have your desired style. e.g `.wrapper ul { }` so `<ul>`s outside the wrapper won't be effected and styles will be applied without the need of a new class on every `<ul>`.